# Really weird white highlights on mesh?

Tags: modeling

Okay I don't know what I did but my mesh with just a diffuse texture looks terrible now. I could use some advice on how to fix this.

Specifically these weird white highlights.
[image]

Comment: I don't see white highlight. I see black terminator artifacts. They are Cycles limitation. You need higher poly or render in different renderer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue I was having. I was using the shader provided by Quixel in there Quixel to Blender three part video series. The output I received from the software was a diffuse, normal, roughness, specular, and reflection at normal. Plugging everything in works fine, but I was plugging things up wrong, and didn't have the y channel flipped for the normal (green channel).

So essentially I just flipped the Y channel on my normal by separating the RGB using a seperate RGB node than using an invert node (for the G) than used a combine RGB node to finish it all off. The intense white was because of the roughness at normal being set wrong (my fault).

I've included pictures to show what I mean and my outcome & to also show that things are showing up as they should now.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Hard to tell from the image alone, Looks like you turned on smooth shading in your mesh.

Try adding an *Edge Split* modifier to the object(s)

Comment: I think I may of figured it out. I'll probably delete this. The shader I'm using has a reflection at normal channel and I must of turned it up somehow, and that is what did it.

Answer (score 0):

From the screenshot I can tell that your pickaxe tries to reflect the color of the background.

Try to turn the background to black and create a few emission objects to light your pickaxe. Do not use lamps

I hope I could help